# how to move slider towards left and right using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I want to drag from a step to other step using selenium java .I referred many posts on stackoverflow  but none of them was relevant to my case I think so.  Below is my HTML code :

```
 <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; font-weight: normal; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 8pt; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;" class="QvSliderObject">
    <div style="width: 711px; height: 61px;">
    <canvas height="61" width="711" style="width: 711px; height: 61px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 21px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">1</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 58px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">2</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 95px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">3</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 132px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">4</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 168px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">5</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 205px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">6</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 242px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">7</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 279px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">8</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 316px; top: 11px; width: 8px; height: 14px;">9</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 350px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">10</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 386px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">11</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 423px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">12</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 460px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">13</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 497px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">14</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 534px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">15</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 571px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">16</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 607px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">17</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 644px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">18</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 8pt; overflow: visible; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; left: 681px; top: 11px; width: 14px; height: 14px;">19</div></canvas> 
<canvas style="width: 8px; height: 12px; position: absolute; left: 646px; top: 40px; cursor: inherit;" width="8" height="12"></canvas>
    <canvas style="width: 10px; height: 12px; position: absolute; left: 696px; top: 40px;" width="10" height="12"></canvas>
    <canvas style="width: 10px; height: 12px; position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 40px;" width="10" height="12"></canvas></div></div>
```

Below is my java code :

```
WebElement sliderLocation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='64']//following::canvas)[2]"));
        // Used points class to get x and y coordinates of element.
        Point classname = sliderLocation.getLocation();
        int xcordi = classname.getX();
        int ycordi = classname.getY();
        int width = sliderLocation.getSize().getWidth();
        System.out.println(
                "Element's Position from left side of window " + xcordi + "and from right side of Window " + ycordi);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Actions move = new Actions(driver);
            Action action1 = (Action) move.dragAndDropBy(sliderLocation, 60, 0).build();
            action1.perform();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and tried all possible solutions suggested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453230/selenium-webdriver-move-slider-on-left-side) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171745/how-to-slidemove-slider-in-selenium-webdriver/19515447) link but still of no use. What should I set in the coordinates section. By default it is on 18 and its coordinates position from left side of window is 1319 and from right side of Window is 252.
I have attached image of that scroll bar . Suppose I want to drag from 18 to 17 so how can I do this ? Please help me . I am badly stuck .
[image]

Comment: Where is the pointer initially located? And where do you want to move ?

Comment: it is located on 18 and I want to move it to 17 or 19 on that slider

Comment: who is your `//*[@id='64']` in the html ?

Comment: its that cursor on slider which i want to drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will move your slider to "17" scale:

```
WebElement sliderLocation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='64']//following::canvas)[2]"));
  WebElement elem17 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='64']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[17]"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(sliderLocation).moveToElement(elem17).release(sliderLocation).build().perform();
```

I am assuming that sliderLocation refers to this element   [image]

Comment: No it is not moving to 17 .sliderLocation is the cursor on the slider which i want to move and the xpath is correct

Comment: Could you share HTML for your slider element in question

Comment: It doesn't throw any error and i have added 3 canvas lines at the end of the html code where the first canvas line is for the the cursor on the slider for which I created custom xpath using firebug

Comment: would it be possible for you to share ur URL?

Comment: Couls you share the result of `elem17.getText(();`

Comment: now it gives this error org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.QvSliderObject canvas div:nth-child(17)"}
Command duration or timeout: 160.08 seconds
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: This could be because the element might be located on a frame or something; this locator is correct as per the required HTML.

Comment: there is nothing such as frame in my html .so any solution for this ?

Comment: Goto `chrome  > developer options > console >type $x("div.QvSliderObject canvas div:nth-child(17)")` and hit enter; what's the outcome?

Comment: its showing invalid xpath expression but it was customized using firebug in mozilla

Comment: So the whole problem lies because of invalid xpath, please provide the xpath provided by firebug

Comment: .//*[@id='64']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[17] this is the xpath for 17 .

Comment: I wanted xpath for elem17?

Comment: Goto chrome > developer options > console >type $$("div.QvSliderObject canvas div:nth-child(17)") and hit enter; what's the outcome?

Comment: Also $$("#64 div>div>div div:nth-child(17)")

Comment: edit your above answer with this line for element 17 and i ll mark it as accepted because my problem is solved now :) i can move right and left by its particular Xpath WebElement elem17 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='64']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[17]")); thanks alot @kushal :)

Comment: delete your other answer kushal :)

Comment: Yes I will, shortly.