# How to handle the slider for particular position or value in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My script is working for slider but it moves only to higher value on the right side.
In the application, default value is 25 and I can't able to change the exact position like from 25 to 65 or 25 to 10, etc..
Even if i use negative value it doesn't show any difference. Kindly resolve this issue, it will very helpful.

```
    driver.get("https://demoqa.com/widgets");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Slider']"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);     

    WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='range']"));

    Actions moveSlider = new Actions(driver);
    Action action = moveSlider.dragAndDropBy(Slider, 30, 0).build();

    action.perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: can you please tell me where i need to use exactly ?

Comment: Sorry , i missed the hylerlink. let me check and confirm

Comment: Sorry , it is not working fine for me. if you show some example for above script, it will be great.

Comment: [Working sample code](https://file.lu/d/IZh)(tested on your link) with some code from NirajUppal from [how to move sliders in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62804040/16653700). This doesn't use `sendKeys`.

Comment: @MuthukumarGangadharan [Refer this answer. I had posted the solution here yesterday to another question. Check the solution for example 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70464501/5331061)

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh - Thank you !!! it is working fine. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @MuthukumarGangadharan Glad it helped you :)