# Unable to perform any actions on elements which were located under flexbox

Tags: python, java, html, selenium, flexbox

`Selenium` is able to `findElement` which were located under <kbd>flex</kbd> box but not able to perform any actions on those elements. Below I am providing couple of sample websites for detailed understanding,

---

#### Example#1:

**Website**: https://condos.ca/

**<kbd>HTML</kbd> snippet**:

```html
<div class="styles___SearchField-sc-ntshwn-1 azZjo">
   <div class="styles___SiteSearch-sc-ntshwn-3 bvlPAF">
  <div class="styles___InputIcon-sc-ntshwn-4 eAuylQ">
     <svg viewBox="0 0 59.93 60" class="styles___Svg-sc-14upfal-0 frvNPk svg-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">
        <path d="M59.23,55.73L44.33,40.81a25,25,0,1,0-3.53,3.54L55.7,59.27A2.5,2.5,0,1,0,59.23,55.73ZM5,25A20,20,0,1,1,25,45,20,20,0,0,1,5,25Z" transform="translate(-0.03)"></path>
     </svg>
  </div>
  <input aria-label="Search by address, Neighbourhood, MLS #" placeholder="Search by address, Neighbourhood, MLS #" id="search-input">
   </div>
   <div class="styles___GetLocationContainer-sc-ntshwn-5 cCBUUE">
  <button target="_blank" name="search nearby button" class="styles___AppButton-sc-5pk18n-0 jXQNUT styles___SearchNearby-sc-ntshwn-6 dYpkAS" id="">
     <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="styles___Svg-sc-14upfal-0 frvNPk svg-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="width: 22px; height: 22px;">
        <path d="M10,17.49c-4.19-0.02-7.57-3.39-7.55-7.53c0.02-4.14,3.42-7.48,7.61-7.47c4.18,0.02,7.56,3.37,7.55,7.51C17.6,14.15,14.19,17.5,10,17.49C10,17.49,10,17.49,10,17.49z M10,3.48C6.37,3.5,3.43,6.43,3.45,10.02c0.02,3.59,2.98,6.5,6.61,6.48c3.62-0.02,6.54-2.92,6.55-6.5c0-3.6-2.95-6.52-6.59-6.52C10.01,3.48,10.01,3.48,10,3.48z"></path>
        <path d="M10,3.48c-0.28,0-0.5-0.22-0.5-0.49V0.49C9.5,0.22,9.72,0,10,0s0.5,0.22,0.5,0.49v2.49C10.5,3.26,10.28,3.48,10,3.48z"></path>
        <path d="M10,20c-0.28,0-0.5-0.22-0.5-0.49v-2.51c0-0.27,0.22-0.49,0.5-0.49s0.5,0.22,0.5,0.49v2.51C10.5,19.78,10.28,20,10,20z"></path>
        <path d="M19.54,10.48h-2.43c-0.28,0-0.5-0.22-0.5-0.49c0-0.27,0.22-0.49,0.5-0.49h2.43c0.28,0,0.5,0.22,0.5,0.49C20.04,10.26,19.82,10.48,19.54,10.48z"></path>
        <path d="M3,10.49H0.46c-0.28,0-0.5-0.22-0.5-0.49c0-0.27,0.22-0.49,0.5-0.49H3c0.28,0,0.5,0.22,0.5,0.49C3.5,10.27,3.28,10.49,3,10.49z"></path>
        <path d="M10,13.49c-1.95-0.02-3.52-1.61-3.5-3.54c0.02-1.93,1.62-3.48,3.58-3.46c1.94,0.02,3.51,1.59,3.5,3.51c-0.01,1.94-1.61,3.5-3.57,3.49C10.01,13.49,10,13.49,10,13.49z M10,7.48C8.6,7.5,7.48,8.64,7.5,10.03c0.02,1.39,1.18,2.49,2.58,2.47c1.38-0.02,2.49-1.13,2.5-2.5c0-1.39-1.14-2.52-2.55-2.52C10.02,7.48,10.01,7.48,10,7.48z"></path>
     </svg>
  </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Code**:

```
driver.get("https://condos.ca");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search-input']")).sendKeys("test");
```

**Result**: Step is being executed without throwing any errors but text was not entered.

---

#### Example#2:

**Website**: https://demoqa.com/slider

**<kbd>HTML</kbd> snippet**:

```html
<div id="sliderContainer" class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-9">
  <span class="range-slider__wrap">
     <input type="range" class="range-slider range-slider--primary" min="0" max="100" value="25" style="--value:25;">
     <div class="range-slider__tooltip range-slider__tooltip--auto range-slider__tooltip--bottom" style="left: calc(25% + 5px);">
        <div class="range-slider__tooltip__label">25</div>
        <div class="range-slider__tooltip__arrow"></div>
     </div>
  </span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3"><input id="sliderValue" class="form-control" value="25"></div>
</div>
```

**Code**:

```
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/slider");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='range']"));
System.out.println("Cuurent value: " + slider.getAttribute("value"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', ' 30 ')", slider);
```

**Result**: Printed attribute value but didn't set the new value.

---

Few SO questions and blogs are suggesting to use **Selenium flex api** to automate these these type of applications but I can see a pre-requiste to install flex plugin for eclipse and I cannot find that. Also, these post are little old (5 years old).

- ***How to handle these elements?***
- ***Is there any new way to do this?***

**References**:

- *[Is selenium automation tool supports flex applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619798/is-selenium-automation-tool-supports-flex-applications)*
- *https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automating-flex-application-selenium-webdriver-himanshu-tewari/*

Comment: have you tried to add some wait / delay before executing those actions? Not implicit wait but explicit wait of element visibility or just a dummy pause to make sure the page is 100% completely loaded?

Comment: Yes. I tried but didn't added in question.

Comment: And this didn't resolve the issue at all?

Comment: Exactly. You can see the reference links what I added in question.

Comment: OK, I see, just wanted to be completely sure. That's an interesting question!

Comment: Incase you wish to reduce the scope of the question to a specific usecase instead of 2 usecases, I would like to attempt to answer :) (currently don't have a IDE for Java, so answer would be Python based)

Comment: Sure @DebanjanB. Any use case is fine for me and I would like to know way of approach to solve this.

Comment: @NandanA In your Example 1, your code does enter a value but that value disappears quickly as it is not a valid Address/Neighbourhood(this is how the application is designed). That editbox require you to not only enter a value but also select an appropriate option suggested by the app based on the value entered

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh Have you tried manually by entering same text? It is not disappearing. It is disappearing when you clicked outside of the textbox. Just now I checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Solution to Example 1**

If you load the website, you will observe that the text above the search editbox  initially looks like:

[image]

After sometime, the same element's text gets changed to:
[image]

Only after this happens, try performing the sendkeys operation. Note that you don't have to perform the sendkeys operation on the element with id = 'search-input'. You first need to click on that element and then another element(cssSelector -> `div[role='combobox'] [placeholder='Search by address, Neighbourhood, MLS #']`) becomes visible on which you have to perform the sendkeys operation.

Please refer the code below for the same(tested on chrome, edge and firefox).

```
package usecase;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Flexcase {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    private static final int maxtime = 20;

    /**
     * Creating a custom findElement method that uses Explicit wait and waits for an
     * element to be clickable
     */
    public static WebElement findElement(By by) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(maxtime));
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
    }

    /**
     * Waits for an element to contain a text matched by the given pattern(regex)
     */
    public static Boolean doesElementContainTextPattern(By by, String pattern) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(maxtime));
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textMatches(by, Pattern.compile(pattern)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://condos.ca/");
        // Waiting for the text to achieve a specific pattern - Search followed by 1+
        // occurrences of either digits or commas followed by 0+ occurrences of any
        // character that is not a newline character followed by the word Listings
        if (doesElementContainTextPattern(By.className("dPFjpJ"), "Search [\\d,]+.*Listings")) {
            findElement(By.id("search-input")).click();
            findElement(By.cssSelector("div[role='combobox'] [placeholder='Search by address, Neighbourhood, MLS #']"))
                    .sendKeys("Test");
        }

        Thread.sleep(10000); // Pls let me see what's happening on the screen
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Demo:**
[image]

**Solution for Example 2**

Instead of using javascriptexecutor, I have used the Actions class to build a composite action made up by following actions:

- move the mouse to leftmost position of the slider by finding the slider width in pixels
- move the mouse to the desired position on the slider proportiante to the percentage value passed

**Code:**(sliding accuracy can be improved)

```
package usecase;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Slider {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void moveSliderToPosition(By by, int percentage) throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement slider = driver.findElement(by);
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(slider, (int) (-slider.getRect().width / 2), 0) // move to the leftmost position of the
                                                                                // element
                .moveByOffset((int) (percentage * slider.getRect().width / 100), 0) // move the cursor by an offset
                                                                                    // proportionate to the value passed
                .click().build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000); // let me see what has happened on the screen
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/slider");
        By slider = By.cssSelector("input.range-slider");
        moveSliderToPosition(slider, 47);
        moveSliderToPosition(slider, 83);
        moveSliderToPosition(slider, 35);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Demo:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will try it out for sure but I have one question. In example#1, why the element (input tag) is visible after clicking on that? If it is not visible it should throw an exception. Your answer for example#2 is awesome.

Comment: Wll, again, that's how the app has been made ;). If you reload the website and press CTRL + SHIFT + I, and in the console tab, you try to find the element `div[role='combobox'] [placeholder='Search by address, Neighbourhood, MLS #']`, you will not be able to find it. But, when you click on the search box and again when you try to search for the same element in console, you will be able to locate it.

Comment: Agreed. Then it should throw the exception but that was not happened 

Comment: It's working as expected for example#2 but still failing for example#1. I tried the example#1 in selenium 3 and 4 versions also and not sure why it is failing.

Comment: hmm...the code still is working on my machine...I am using Selenium 4 too...What exactly is happening at your end when you say it is not working? Does it not enter any text at all? or does the entered disappear quickly? Can you try to run in the debug mode? or add log statements or add hard-coded waits just to see at which point the code is failing to do what is expected...and then maybe we can proceed with its resolution

Comment: I tried all the ways what you have mentioned. The code is being executed without throwing any error so I am thinking what could be the reason.